# Border around arbitrary neighbouring divs, even if the borders are crossing

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, anki

I have a Chinese sentence where each character (and its pinyin) live in a div. Now different characters can form different words, and I want to create borders around the characters to show which words they potentially form. The tricky thing is that sometimes it is not obvious which word is really formed, so there can be crossing circles.

Consider the following example, the first sentence from the novel "To Live" from Yu Hua: 我比现在年轻十岁的时候， 获得了一个游手好闲的职业， 去乡间收集民间歌谣。

In the second third, there are the three characters "获得了" which can form the words "获得" or "得了". To indicate this, I want a border around "获得" and a border around "得了".

Unfortunately I can't post an image because I don't have 10 reputation.

The problem is that I think normal divs aren't enough here, because the divs would be crossing, which is not possible. A table layout gets too complicated quickly. I don't want to assign the rectangles dynamically using JavaScript either, because I want to show all words at the same time. Is maybe a HTML5 canvas the solution?

Here's the structure of the divs (only the three examples):

```html
<div class="hanzi_with_pinyin"><div class="hanzi color4">获</div><div class="pinyins_div"><div class="pinyin_div color4">huo4</div></div></div>
<div class="hanzi_with_pinyin"><div class="hanzi">得</div><div class="pinyins_div"><div class="pinyin_div color2">de2</div><div class="pinyin_div color5">de5</div><div class="pinyin_div color3">dei3</div></div></div>
<div class="hanzi_with_pinyin"><div class="hanzi">了</div><div class="pinyins_div"><div class="pinyin_div color5">le5</div><div class="pinyin_div color3">liao3</div><div class="pinyin_div color4">liao4</div></div></div>
```

**Is there an easy way which will allow me to create rectangles around neighboring divs, even if the rectangles are crossing?**

Answer (score 0):

Use table borders along with the `<tr>` and `<th>` tags like so.

https://www.html.am/html-codes/tables/table-border.cfm

Example:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th><div class="hanzi_with_pinyin"><div class="hanzi color4">获</div><div class="pinyins_div"><div class="pinyin_div color4">huo4</div></div></div></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div class="hanzi_with_pinyin"><div class="hanzi">得</div><div class="pinyins_div"><div class="pinyin_div color2">de2</div><div class="pinyin_div color5">de5</div><div class="pinyin_div color3">dei3</div></div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="hanzi_with_pinyin"><div class="hanzi">了</div><div class="pinyins_div"><div class="pinyin_div color5">le5</div><div class="pinyin_div color3">liao3</div><div class="pinyin_div color4">liao4</div></div></div></td></tr>
</table>
```

You can further customize it by using css borders too.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp